# Why is the range of inverse trigonometric functions defined in this way?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is really simple, why is the range of the $\sin^{-1}(x)$, $\cos^{-1}(x)$ and $\tan^{-1}(x)$ defined as $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $[0,\pi]$ and $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ respectively? Is there some particular reason? We could choose another range for each inverse trigonometric function. For example, we can pick $[0,\pi]$ to be the range of $\sin^{-1}x$.

**EDIT**

I've understood why the range of the sine and cosine has to be $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $[0,\pi]$ respectively. I'm still wondering why can't we define the range of the tangent as $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why cannot $[0;\pi]$ be range of $\arcsin$?

Because at this range $\sin$ is not injective. It means that there exist $a,b\in[0;\pi],\;a\ne b$, that $\sin(a)=\sin(b)$. This is very inconvenient because $\arcsin$ would be multivalued. For one argument there would exist two values. That's why such range is selected that $\sin$ is injective and thus $\arcsin$ is a function.

---

Function $\sin(x)$ is periodic. It means that for every value $y$ there exist infinitely many arguments $x$ satisfying $y=\sin(x)$. Then, its inverse $\arcsin$ is multivalued. For every argument it takes infinitely many values. That's why we usually "split" it into branches, so that every branch is a function. It is usually done at points where tangent is vertical. Then we define such branches as $$...,\;\arcsin_{-1}(x),\;\arcsin_0(x),\;\arcsin_1(x),...$$

The branch $\arcsin_0(x)$ is the principal one, equivalent to $\arcsin(x)$.

Reasoning behind $\arccos$ is analogous.

---

Similar thing goes with $\tan$. It is not injective, so we take such domain (this selected domain of $\tan$ is the range of $\arctan$) that $\tan$ is injective on it. It is $$...,\;(-3\pi/2;-\pi/2),\;(-\pi/2;\pi/2),\;(\pi/2,3\pi/2),\;...$$

Actually we can take domains such as $[0;\pi)$, but then, $\arctan$ would not be continuous.

Why the domain that is closest to $0$ is selected? Because it's convenient.

Comment: ok, I understood why this range is more convenient to the sine inverse function. What about the inverse of the tangent? why can't it be $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: the range of the tangent could be $[0,\pi]$ also, no?

Comment: @user42912 yes, but it would be very problematic. It wouldn't be continuous at $x=0$ (see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f6s8hibtio)). Also, which value ($0$ or $\pi$) choose for $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Inverse trigo functions are nothing but angles . Now trigo functions are periodic over $2π$ so there ranges are such also range of tan is $[-π/2,π/2]$ hope i have intrtpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another choice.  As I recall there are two different ways that calculus textbooks define $\sec^{-1}$.

Another answer.  In complex analysis, each of these inverse trig functions may be written in terms of the complex (natural) logarithm.  So take that definition, and use the **principal value** of the log to get the principal value for the inverse trig functions.  Then restrict to the real line for baby use.